# Append security rights to a folder via Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2012

Trying my hand at Powershell and I'm trying to figure out how to add specific permissions to our user account. The code below will add the service account to the folders `Security` tab, however it will not adjust the permissions. Any idea why?

```
#variables
$okeeffename = "WCFService"
$domain = "InsideServices.dev.com"
$okeeffedirectory = "d:\webcontent\$domain\$okeeffename"

#create webcontent and application folders
Write-Host "Creating directories" -ForegroundColor Yellow
New-Item -Path $okeeffedirectory -type directory -ErrorAction Stop

#adjust security for folders
$okeefferights = Get-Acl $okeeffedirectory
$read = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($useraccount, "Read", "Allow")
$list = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($useraccount, "ListDirectory", "Allow")
$readexecute = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($useraccount, "ReadAndExecute", "Allow")
$okeefferights.SetAccessRule($read)
$okeefferights.SetAccessRule($list)
$okeefferights.SetAccessRule($readexecute)
Set-Acl -Path $okeeffedirectory -AclObject $okeefferights
```

Second question: I'm trying to add the following permissions for the service account to the folder. Can someone point out the keyword Powershell uses for the `List Folder Contents` permission?

[image]

**EDIT**

By toggling the `Allow`/`Deny` value for the `FileSystemRights` I found that each of the specs are only changing the `Special Permissions` Permission on the folder. Quick screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy to find out when you know what exactly you are looking for. What you need is a `[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]`. We can find the available rights list by using [enum] as such:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> [enum]::GetNames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights])

ListDirectory
ReadData
WriteData
CreateFiles
CreateDirectories
AppendData
ReadExtendedAttributes
WriteExtendedAttributes
Traverse
ExecuteFile
DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles
ReadAttributes
WriteAttributes
Write
Delete
ReadPermissions
Read
ReadAndExecute
Modify
ChangePermissions
TakeOwnership
Synchronize
FullControl
```

You can create several rights in one object like (this should allow a user read/execute only access to a folder and its' contents):

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ListDirectory,ReadData,Traverse,ExecuteFile,ReadAttributes,ReadPermissions,Read,ReadAndExecute"
```

My usual template for setting ACLs is this:

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl" 

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit"
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Domain\User") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $Rights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL "C:\Temp" 
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

Set-ACL "C:\Temp" $objACL
```

From that you should be able to manipulate the code to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Is there a site or tutorial you'd recommend for learning the syntax?

Comment: I wish... unfortunately learning this all myself was rather challenging. There's some good threads here on SO that you could read through to help.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To build an ACE that shows up as "list folder contents" in the "Security" tab you need to combine 5 [file system rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- `ListDirectory`
- `ReadAttributes`
- `ReadExtendedAttributes`
- `ReadPermissions`
- `Traverse`

and set inheritance to `ContainerInherit`.

```
$list = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($useraccount, 'Traverse,ListDirectory,ReadAttributes,ReadExtendedAttributes,ReadPermissions', 'ContainerInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
```

---

the most straightforward way to find out the specific combination of file system rights and inheritance flags for a particular ACE is to create it manually and inspect the result in the Advanced Security Settings:

[image: "Security" tab of properties dialog]
[image: "Advanced Security Settings" dialog]
[image: "Change Advanced Security Settings" dialog]
[image: "Permission Entry" dialog]