# NTFS permission

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I want to add a user to NTFS Permission and give full control to a specific folder.

This is the code that I found in internet, but it gives me an error.

```
Set-ACL -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST" -Account "DESKTOP-R5C0QAA\Bobby" -AccessRights FullControl
Set-Acl : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Account'.
At line:1 char:45
Set-ACL -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST" -Account "DESKTOP-R5C0QAA ...
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Acl], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: as WaiHaLee mentioned, the lack of any hint of what went wrong is ... pretty much a show-stopper. [*grin*] however, the cmdlet you list is NOT installed by default. did you install the module that it comes from?

Comment: Probably you will have to install the according module [NTFSSecurity](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.4) first. You might start with learning the very basics of Powershell first. ;-)

Comment: Have you tried looking for similar questions here on StackOverflow? Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310436/3245749) will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting NTFS Permissions With Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336969/setting-ntfs-permissions-with-powershell)

Comment: Hey Bob, running `get-help set-acl` will tell you the available options for `set-acl` and yoiu'll find it expects a completely different set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here the easiest way i could find.

```
Install-Module NTFSSecurity
Add-NTFSAccess –Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST" –Account "DESKTOP-R5C0QAA\Bobby" –AccessRights FullControl
```

[More info here on NTFS Security module](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fieldcoding/2014/12/05/ntfssecurity-tutorial-1-getting-adding-and-removing-permissions/)